# What am I not understanding about these sentences?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, gerunds

I'm so confused by the sentences.

> 1.They miss being in Brazil
>
> 2.They miss having been in Brazil
>
> 3.They missed being in Brazil
>
> 4.They missed having been in Brazil

So 1 means that they miss the time they were in Brazil. 2 I think it means the same as the former sentence but I'm not sure. Then 3 means a time ago they were missing the time they were in brazil that was prior to the time they were nostalgic and 4 means the same as 3. So the thing is I'm not sure about this and I can't understand why 1&2 and 3&4 mean the same if they are different forms.

Answer (score 1):

1 and 3 make sense. 2 and 4 don't make sense. You can miss something that is in the past, like "being in Brazil".  When you say you "miss" something, it is because you once had it, and now it is gone.

[American Heritage Dictionary "miss"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=miss)
11. To feel the lack or loss of:
*Do you miss your family?*

If I have ever been in Brazil, it will always be true that I have been there; I can't lose that, so I can't feel the loss of it.

This is a semantic question, not a grammatical one.

Comment: what do you mean by "description of a present state"  and that "is not something in the past"?

Comment: If I have ever been in Brazil, it will be true for the rest of my life that "I have been in Brazil." My being in Brazil is in the past, but my having been in Brazil is true now and forever. Do you understand now?

Comment: i think so. But you say that your being in brazil,i agree your having been is a description of your present state that is true(i never questioned that) but its also in the past because "you have been there" not in the present. That is my question. another one is how come "having been in brazil" is description of a present state and you cant miss it but "being in brazil" (you did not say if it is a description like "having been") and you can miss it?

Comment: I tried to clarify my answer by focusing on the meaning of "miss". Maybe that will explain it better.